# RadioButtonList set to AutoPostBack = true but still not firing OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 RadioButtonLists and I want only one option to be selected, f.i. if you select an option in List 1 the selection in List 2 should be cleared.

AutoPostBack and EnableViewState is set to true, but still the Method never fires. I have also checked if the Index actually changes, it does. I think that the PostBack just doesn't occur, but I don'T know why.

I'm thankful for any help.

ascx:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="_listOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListOneIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="_listTwo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListTwoIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ListOneIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listTwo.ClearSelection();
}
protected void ListTwoIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listOne.ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: `"I think that the PostBack just doesn't occur"` - Have you verified this?  The browser's debugging tools will tell you if a request is made, what the response is, if there are any client-side errors, etc.  Does anything happen in the `Page_Load` event during the post-back which stops this?  Maybe the lists are re-populated in that method and the selection changed event is lost?  You need to debug this a little.

Comment: Are you using updatepanels at all?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that there is no request. Nothing happens in the Page_Load and the lists are also not repopulated. When I submit the page the right Index is submitted, so I think the index actually changes?

Comment: @wingyip No I am not using updatepanels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the control to RadioButton and add GroupName to them will do the trick:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="_listOne" runat="server" GroupName="xx" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListOneIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButton>
<asp:RadioButton ID="_listTwo" runat="server" GroupName="xx" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListTwoIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButton>
```

Comment: I will try doing that, even though I will have to create them in the .cs since I don't know how many RadioButtons there will be.

Comment: wrap them up in a panel or some container, then you can use `panel.Controls.Add`

Comment: Shouldn't the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` actually be `OnCheckedChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

try to use just one radibuttonlist and options.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList id="radiolist1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListOneIndexChanged">

   <asp:ListItem selected="true">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I can't use just one, there is content between them.